# GeoServer WFS viewparams Not Working with Multiple Parameters

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I'm having an issue with setting multiple parameters in the viewparams of a GeoServer Web Feature Service (WFS) request. Specifically, I'm trying to set both district_id and auction_land_status_id parameters, but it's not working as expected.

I have constructed my WFS URL like this:

```
const wfsUrl = `${gsUrl}/wfs?` +
  'service=WFS&' +
  'version=1.1.0&' +
  'request=GetFeature&' +
  'typename=egkn:freelands_view&' +
  `viewparams=district_id:${districtId};auction_land_status_id:93&` +
  'outputFormat=application/json&' +
  'srsname=EPSG:404000&' +
  'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:404000';
```

When I include only district_id in viewparams everything works correctly, however, when I include both district_id and auction_land_status_id in the viewparams, the request doesn't seem to apply the auction_land_status_id filter, and I still get results as if I only used district_id.

I've verified that both parameters are integers, and I'm using the correct URL encoding. Additionally, I've tried changing the order of the parameters, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with GeoServer's WFS service, especially when using multiple viewparams? Any insights or suggestions on how to correctly set multiple parameters in viewparams?

Comment: looks like your quotes are wrong on that line

Comment: Can't see how you'll be able to add any useful bounding box when the data has no known coordinate system (EPSG:404000)

Comment: @IanTurton No, they are like this on purpose, so that I will be able to pass districtId like this {districtId}; And with just the districtId as the param everything works fine, as I mention before, so the problem is not quotes

Comment: @nmtoken I am not sure what exactly do you mean, because I am new to all of this, but I am using EPSG:404000 because on the GeoServer, on the 'freelands_view' layer page the Declared SRS is 404000, and native is empty. I don't know what it means, but I guess it is the right way, because with EPSG:3857 it didn't work well

Comment: You need to turn up the logging and then add the relevant part of the log file for a failing request.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/epsg-40400/info